# методы класса не отображаются при выводе всех свойств объекта

Tags: javascript

Есть три варианта объекта. Почему во втором варианте **Obj2**, методы объявленные в самом классе, а не в конструкторе, при выводе всех свойств объекта в цикле, не отображаются? Ведь теоретически, они должны быть свойствами объекта? Спасибо.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

 class Obj1 {
  constructor(num, str) {
   this.num = num;
   this.str = str;
   this.fun1 = function () {
    return this.num;
   };
   this.fun2 = function () {
    return this.str;
   };
  }
 }

 let obj1 = new Obj1(5, 'Five');
 console.log(obj1);
 console.log(obj1.fun1());
 for (let i in obj1) {
  console.log(i);
 }
 console.log(' ');

 //----------------------------

 class Obj2 {
  constructor(num, str) {
   this.num = num;
   this.str = str;
  }
  fun1() {
   return this.num;
  }
  fun2() {
   return this.str;
  }
 }

 let obj2 = new Obj2(10, 'Ten');
 console.log(obj2);
 console.log(obj2.fun1());
 for (let i in obj2) {
  console.log(i);
 }
 console.log(' ');

 //----------------------------

 let obj3 = {
  num: 15,
  str: 'Fifteen',
  fun1: function () {
   return this.num;
  },
  fun2: function () {
   return this.str;
  }
 };

 console.log(obj3);
 console.log(obj3.fun1());
 for (let i in obj3) {
  console.log(i);
 }

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### почему

потому, что они в прототипе
https://learn.javascript.ru/new-prototype
[https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype#метод-hasownproperty](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-hasownproperty)
[Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute)

### es6

```
 class Obj2 {
  constructor(num, str) {
   this.num = num;
   this.str = str;
  }
  fun1() {
   return this.num;
  }
  fun2() {
   return this.str;
  }
 }
```

### es3

```
var Obj2 = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Obj2(num, str) {
        this.num = num;
        this.str = str;
    }
    Obj2.prototype.fun1 = function () {
        return this.num;
    };
    Obj2.prototype.fun2 = function () {
        return this.str;
    };
    return Obj2;
}());
```

Comment: Уважаемый qwabra! Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: @Anton,  https://learn.javascript.ru/prototype#метод-hasownproperty `Obj2.hasOwnProperty('fun1') //false`

Comment: [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute)

Comment: Уважаемый qwabra!  Еще раз большое спасибо за информацию! Буду разбираться.